# Does this AppleScript/shell code expose input in plain text in any way?

Tags: shell, hash, applescript, md5

I would appreciate response from anyone with knowledge of nuts'n'bolts of Unix/macOS.

Does running this code on a local machine expose the input in plain text to any processes/logs/etc.?

I'm obviously most interested in the bracket of background processes occurring from when the keystrokes are captured to when the hashing occurs.

`do shell script "md5 -q -s " & quoted form of text returned of (display dialog "Input I would like to keep unexposed:" default answer "" default button 1 buttons {"Make hash"} with hidden answer)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does expose it. At the very least, the command and its arguments (including the input string) are available via the `ps` command (and probably other interfaces) for as long as the command is running.